# __attribute__ format for specific specifiers?

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

I would like to give the users of my API the possibility to pass a custom format string.

Now, I know what kind of specifiers I am expecting (for a single double), and I would like to make clang aware of this.

The [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) (which actually just points to the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) makes it seem as if I could only specify the format in terms of actual parameters to my function/method.

However, I would just like to tell clang: "If it contains one, and only one %f specifier (with whatever flags, width or precision the caller would like), it's OK"

I can't seem to find that information. Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear as it seems to discuss unrelated things. Can you clarify with some code samples - what exactly would you like to see?

Comment: @EliBendersky: Sounds to me that the questioner wants to define a restricted subset of the `printf` format syntax and have the compiler reject anything that does not conform to it.

Comment: Peter Horsey, you are right, this was my intention. If not reject, at least warn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `gcc` documentation, I don't think there's a way to directly do what you want.
(I'm assuming that your goal is to require a format suitable for printing a single `float`.)
The closest thing I can think of, is if you have your function `void myfunc(const char *fmt)`
you could rewrite it as

```
extern void do_myfunc(const char *fmt); /* the real body of myfunc() */
inline void myfunc(const char *fmt) { /* put this in the header */
    if (0) {
        float f = 0.0f;
        printf(fmt, f);
    }
    do_myfunc(fmt);
}
```

and rely on `clang` to remove the dead code. Of course, `clang` might complain about said dead code, then...

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicion: Apparently, there is no way to (elegantly) do this :(